# Blazor server-side: subscribe to event

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, events, blazor

I am having trouble to understand how can I subscribe to an event in a Blazor page.

I have this class which implements Quartz's .NET `IJobListener` interface:

```
public class GlobalJobListener : IJobListener
    {
        public event TaskExecution Started;
        public event TaskExecution Vetoed;
        public event TaskExecutionComplete Executed;

        public GlobalJobListener(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public GlobalJobListener()
        {
           
        }

        public Task JobToBeExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var task = new Task(() => Started?.Invoke());
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();
            return task;
        }

        public Task JobExecutionVetoed(IJobExecutionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var task = new Task(() => Vetoed?.Invoke());
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();
            return task;
        }

        public Task JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var task = new Task(() => Executed?.Invoke(jobException));
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();
            return task;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
    }
```

In `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<GlobalJobListener>();
```

Then in my .razor page:

```
[Inject]
 protected GlobalJobListener listener { get; set; }
```

And `OnInitializedAsync()`:

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            scheduler = quartz.Scheduler;
            if (scheduler != null)
            {                
                listener.Started += BeforeStart;
                listener.Executed += AfterEndAsync;
            }
        }
  private void BeforeStart()
        {           
            Log.Information("\t" + "Started: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
        }
```

And `BeforeStart()` never triggers, but `JobToBeExecuted()` triggers OK. I can't manage to see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What actually starts whatever "job" this is?  You hook up the event in an async startup method, so could it be that the event fired before that linkage actually occurred?

Comment: Try to use "private Task BeforeStart()" instead of "private void BeforeStart()", and make your method return Task.CompletedTask